# What type of variables should I use for gradient boosting machines algorithm?

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting

I'm building a classifier using GBM algorithm, in R. The target data is binary of type chr.

Here is the data summary:

```
> glimpse(data)
Rows: 1,523
Columns: 15
$ PD                                         <chr> "Progressive", "nonProgressive", "nonProgressive", "Progressive", "Pr…
$ gender                                     <chr> "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1",…
$ cancer_type_Breast                         <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ cancer_type_Colorectal                     <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ cancer_type_Melanoma                       <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, …
$ cancer_type_NSCLC                          <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ `cancer_type_Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma`   <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ cancer_type_Sarcoma                        <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ `cancer_type_Thymic Carcinoma`             <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ `cancer_type_Urothelial Bladder Carcinoma` <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ `Treatment_1`                              <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ `Treatment_2`                              <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, …
$ `Treatment_3`                              <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ `Treatment_4`                              <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ age                                        <dbl> 57.52787, 52.35419, 63.71776, 59.35896, 53.76967, 61.68596, 57.62372,…
>
```

You can see the `gender` variable is also binary. For now, it is also type chr but that I think is not suitable for GBM. what data type should it be? I mean, should I convert it to `as.numeric()` or `as.factor()` maybe?

And also what about the `age` variable? it says `dbl`, does it mean that it is type float (like in python) ? cause it's just a continuous variable.

Comment: I love the five decimals in the `age` column. Assuming that `age` is given in years, this means that they got people's ages down to the half-hour. One wonders whether they were counting from conception or from birth. Compare this spurious precision to the crude 0-1 coding for all the other variables.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: Did `age` account for daylight saving time status at the locality of the user's birthplace?

Comment: @usεr11852: or the place of conception...

Comment: @StephanKolassa Those ages were predicted using linear regression, I just forgot to round them XD

Comment: Hm. If those ages are predictions themselves, then I hope you account for the uncertainty this will propagate to your classification.

Comment: Yes. I got the data with many of the age values missing, so I trained a linear reg model to predict the ages and filled in the missing values. I don't know if this is a good idea but we'll see @StephanKolassa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether *binary* variables are coded as characters, factors or numerics should make precisely no difference. Internally, they will all be converted to a single column with 0 or 1. You can test this: fit your model with the data as it is right now, and predict. Then do the same, but convert `gender` first. You should get the exact same predictions.

`age` is a double precision floating point number. This is completely fine here. (Spuriously precise, though.)

Comment: +1. Especially for binary variable pre-setting as `is_male` 0/1  is easier cause we don't have to look up what is the reference category. For the multinomial ones here as they don't have a lot of categories one-hot encoding is still fine most likely but we should ensure we get appropriate stratification when cross-validating.